# Recursive function, depending on number of steps, gives different answers

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

first time user here, hope I didn't miss any similar questions to this one.

The problem I'm having is that we're supposed to write code that will use a recursive function to take an array(array1[n]), then create a second array(array2[n]) in which the members of array2 would be the sum of all elements left to them in the first array which are positive. array2[0] is to be =0, array2[1]=array1[0], array2[2]=array1[0]+array1[1],....

Problem is, I keep trying to think of an algorithm, but I keep coming back to the same code, and I'm no less stumped than before. I thought of a few ways to alter the recursion in order to fix it, but that just made it more broken.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int array[], int tmp)
{
   if(tmp < 0)
       return 0;
   else
       return array[tmp] + sum(array, tmp-1);

}
int main()
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int a[n], b[n], i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     if(a[i] < 0)
         a[i] = 0;
   }
   b[0]=0;
   for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
   {
     int sum1 = 0;
     for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
         sum1 += sum(a,j);

     b[i] = sum1;

   }
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
     printf("%d ",b[i]);

   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int array[],int tmp){
    if(tmp<0)
        return 0;
    else
        return array[tmp] + sum(array, tmp-1);
}

int main(void){
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n], b[n+1], i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if(a[i] < 0)
            a[i] = 0;
    }

    b[0] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        b[i+1] = sum(a, i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't quite exact, as I needed the second array to have the same amount of elements, but after replacing b[n+1] with b[n], it came out right. Thanks again, I'm gonna go see where my code was wrong.

Comment: I don't understand you say.

Comment: What I'm saying is array1 and array2 both have a size of n. Basically, the last element of array1 is ignored.